# Rails 7 misdirecting to another scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Console

```
Started GET "/supervisor_session/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-12-12 22:03:32 +0200
Processing by SupervisorSessionController#new as TURBO_STREAM
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering supervisor_session/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered supervisor_session/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 4.3ms | Allocations: 1988)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 7.4ms | Allocations: 4361)
Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 8.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms | Allocations: 11337)


Started POST "/supervisor_session" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-12-12 22:03:37 +0200
Processing by SupervisorSessionController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "supervisor"=>{"email"=>"root@root.root", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
  Supervisor Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "supervisors".* FROM "supervisors" WHERE "supervisors"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "root@root.root"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/supervisor_session_controller.rb:7:in `create'
#<Supervisor id: 2, first_name: "root", last_name: "root", password_digest: [FILTERED], password_salt: [FILTERED], email: "root@root.root", phone_number: "00">Redirected to http://localhost:3000/administrator_session/main_menu/new?allow_other_host=true

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                             LOOK HERE

Completed 302 Found in 337ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 2839)


Started GET "/administrator_session/main_menu/new?allow_other_host=true" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-12-12 22:03:38 +0200
Processing by MainMenuController#new as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"allow_other_host"=>"true"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 734)


  
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)):
  
app/helpers/logged_in_user_helper.rb:8:in `LoggedInUserConstructor'
app/controllers/main_menu_controller.rb:4:in `new'
```

supervisor_session.rb

```
class SupervisorSessionController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @supervisor = Supervisor.new
  end

  def create
    @supervisor = Supervisor.find_by(email: params[:supervisor][:email])
    print @supervisor.inspect
    if @supervisor && @supervisor.authenticate(params[:supervisor][:password])
      session[:supervisor_id] = @supervisor.id
      session[:first_name]    = @supervisor.first_name
      session[:last_name]     = @supervisor.last_name
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to controller: :main_menu, action: :new , allow_other_host: true}
      end
          
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Login failed"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:supervisor_id] = nil
    redirect_to '/', flash: { error: "Please Retry" }
  end

  private
      # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def supervisor_session__params
      params.require(:supervisor_session).permit(:email,:password_digest)
    end
end
```

I can't seem to login as supervisor despite having a session for one

Note: I used this tutorial, except for the helper for I need multiple types of users
https://dev.to/kevinluo201/building-a-simple-authentication-in-rails-7-from-scratch-2dhb

Comment: `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2))` is the error, and `app/helpers/logged_in_user_helper.rb:8:in 'LoggedInUserConstructor'` is the location of that error.

Comment: LoggedInUserConstructor is a view helper which is supposed to take supervisor and whatever object detailed in the session object, to use only the first and last name to view.

I'm trying to see if the bad routing issue is solved, would losing my session also be solved as well; if I get logged into supervisor_session while using POST, why should I lose it?